# Import Error on Google AppEngine : No module named oauth2

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, python-2.7, importerror

Im running Google AppEngine. I have oauth2 installed. Im successfully able to import oauth2 in  program but when I run my python application using GoogleAppEngine Launcher on localhost, then I get the following error

```
ImportError: No module named oauth2
```

Im using Python2.7 which is not the default version of GoogleAppEngine, but I have changed the  python path both in my project and in GoogleAppEngine Launcher.

Comment: from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
    import oauth2 as oauth
    
    
    class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
            self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')
    
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                         [('/', MainPage)],
                                         debug=True)
    
    def main():
        run_wsgi_app(application)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

Comment: Code from the following link - http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingwebapp.html with "import oauth2 as oauth"

Comment: Have you bundled the oauth library in your app? It has to be uploaded with your app, or App Engine won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/wiki/OAuth2)? It shows OAuth2 being used in a Google App Engine Python project. This might give you a better sense of how to use OAuth2 and GAE.

Comment: This is when you want to create an application which authenticates using oauth2. I want to use oauth2 to connect to Twitter. The error I get mostly looks like a PATH error

Comment: I just realized that this is not a problem with oaoth2. There is an import error with any external library. The same ImportError is happening when I try to import nltk

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to authenticate inbound HTTP requests on App Engine using OAuth2?

I just posted a full end to end example here:
  [google app engine oauth2 provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810607/google-app-engine-oauth2-provider/10855271#10855271)