# google app engine oauth2 provider

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I want to set up a rest api with an oauth 2.0 provider for authentication.I use python.
is there any library for setting up an oauth 2.0 provider coded in python that runs on app engine ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

OAuth2 support in builtin on both the Python and Java App Engine runtimes.

In Python all you need is:

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth

# Note, unlike in the Android app below, there's no 'oauth2:' prefix here
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'

# magic happens here
user = oauth.get_current_user(SCOPE)
```

In Java you would use:

```java
OAuthService oauth = OAuthServiceFactory.getOAuthService();

// Note, unlike in the Android app below, there's no 'oauth2:' prefix here
String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

// magic happens here
User user = oauth.getCurrentUser(SCOPE);
```

Here's the full Python 2.7 handler which will allow you to verify the user:

```py
from google.appengine.api import oauth
import logging
import traceback
import webapp2


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.write('Hi there!\n')

    # Note, unlike in the Android app below, there's no 'oauth2:' prefix here
    scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    try:
      self.response.write('\noauth.get_current_user(%s)' % repr(scope))

      # validates audience of the OAuth2 access token
      allowed_clients = ['407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com'] # list your client ids here
      token_audience = oauth.get_client_id(scope)
      if token_audience not in allowed_clients:
        raise oauth.OAuthRequestError('audience of token \'%s\' is not in allowed list (%s)' % (token_audience, allowed_clients))          

      # gets user object for the user represented by the oauth token
      user = oauth.get_current_user(scope)
      self.response.write(' = %s\n' % user)
      self.response.write('- auth_domain = %s\n' % user.auth_domain())
      self.response.write('- email       = %s\n' % user.email())
      self.response.write('- nickname    = %s\n' % user.nickname())
      self.response.write('- user_id     = %s\n' % user.user_id())
    except oauth.OAuthRequestError, e:
      self.response.set_status(401)
      self.response.write(' -> %s %s\n' % (e.__class__.__name__, e.message))
      logging.warn(traceback.format_exc())


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/.*', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

The app.yaml is trivial

```
application: your-app-id
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app
```

Note that client should send the OAuth2 token in an `Authorization: Bearer` HTTP Request Header, e.g.

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29XAHES6ZT4w72FecXjZu4ZWskTSX3x3OqYxUSTIrA2IfxDDPpI
```

If you happen to be building an Android app, you can easily generate these tokens using the `AccountManager` interface:

```java
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

// TODO: Allow the user to specify which account to authenticate with
for (Account account : accounts) {
  Log.i(TAG, "- account.name = " + account.name);
}

// Note the "oauth2:" prefix here
String authTokenType = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";

// Note: AccountManager will cache these token, even after they've expired.
// TODO: Invalidate expired tokens, either after auth fails, or preemptively via:
// accountManager.invalidateAuthToken(accounts[0].type, token);

accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0], authTokenType, null, this,
    new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
      @Override
      public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
        try {
          String token = future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
          Log.i(TAG, "Got KEY_AUTHTOKEN: " + token);
          // Don't forget HTTP Header "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
          callAppEngineRestApi(token); // <---- Your code here
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
          Log.i(TAG, "The user has denied you access to the API");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.i(TAG, "Exception: ", e);
        }
      }
    }, null);
```

If you'd like to see everything put together, feel free to checkout these projects for the full source:

- https://github.com/fredsa/sauer.motivate-android Android client app
- https://github.com/fredsa/sauer.motivate-appengine Python 2.7 App Engine app
- https://github.com/fredsa/sauer.echo-headers Java App Engine app

Comment: are you sure? Afaik Gae supports just Oauth 1.0a

Comment: I was tested you code but it is not works produce - Exception: <class 'google.appengine.api.oauth.oauth_api.NotAllowedError'> - I was use python 2.5.

Comment: Looked around quite a bit around Google and StackOverflow. This is the only answer with nice working code I have found. (see the supplied URLs for a complete example).
Worked for Java too, hence question title may be misleading java users away.

Comment: Amazing. Took me weeks trying to work with OAuth 2.0 on appengine with python, and this seems to be the ONLY article that talks about `oauth.get_current_user(scope)`. It's not even on the docs, but for me this did the charm!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [OAuth for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/) article information? It says that it is for "This reference describes how to use OAuth with Python applications as the service provider. "

Comment: that uses google for authentication not my service which makes my authentication completely depend on google!

Comment: Then look at [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) for a complete OAuth implementation in Python.

Comment: i think that despite the name it can be used for creating only oauth 1.0 providers

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the above answer so I have added it here for anyone struggling with this snippet:

```
# magic happens here
user = oauth.get_current_user(SCOPE)
```

This has been broken on AppEngine for a month if you're using service accounts (and as of today, I think also Google user tokens) as the token length causes issues in the AE library. Google have told me they are unlikely to fix it soon.

This is the only thing that works for me, at the moment:

```
    token = self.request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1]
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=' + token
    oauth_response = urlfetch.fetch(url)
    if oauth_response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('Unable to authorise: {}/{}'.format(oauth_response.status_code, oauth_response.content))
    token_response = json.loads(oauth_response.content)
    email = token_response['email']
```

Comment: What does this do? What is the logic behind it?

Comment: It uses a google rest api to 'decode' the bearer token, extracting the email address from the response.