# Compute Engine OAuth tokens are invalid to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-oauth, service-accounts

I've noticed that service accounts on GCE instances now have a much longer token than before, and I suspect they are causing AppEngine applications to be unable to work with them, resulting in an InvalidOAuthParametersError.

I obtain a token from a Compute Engine instance like this:

```
# curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
{"access_token":".......","expires_in":2544,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

If I take the resulting 153 character token and POST it to an AppEngine Python application in an 'Authorisation: Bearer ...' header, it causes the app to fail. The app works fine with a shorter (73 character) token generated for a user account.

The Oauth bit of the App that throws the exception is:

```
    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
    email = oauth.get_current_user(SCOPE).email().lower()
```

The error from AppEngine is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/...../v4.398557956806027726/oauth.py", line 13, in post
    user_name = self._get_authd_user()
  File "/...../v4.398557956806027726/oauth.py", line 36, in _get_authd_user
    email = oauth.get_current_user(SCOPE).email().lower()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/oauth/oauth_api.py", line 109, in get_current_user
    _maybe_call_get_oauth_user(_scope)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/oauth/oauth_api.py", line 220, in _maybe_call_get_oauth_user
    _maybe_raise_exception()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/oauth/oauth_api.py", line 237, in _maybe_raise_exception
    raise InvalidOAuthParametersError(error_detail)
InvalidOAuthParametersError
```

If I truncate the token to 73 characters, I see an InvalidOauthToken error (as you'd expect). If I use the full token at https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=... then it returns correct information for the service account, including the correct scopes (userinfo.email).

I'm also 99% sure that the tokens were shorter last week, and that they worked fine in this scenario.

My question is: why does AppEngine think that these service account tokens are invalid? The error would seem to suggest that it is the length causing the issue, or perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: No, and as I recall I even raised the issue with Google and they had no help to give me. I posted a link to this as an answer but some kind SO admin removed it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810607/google-app-engine-oauth2-provider/42537386#42537386